# Angular sync validator as async

Tags: angular, typescript

#### Is possible to use the sync validator in the async validator?

I trying to reuse the sync validator in async validator, but I don't know how to properly return the sync validator.

This doesn't work cause the the `Validators.minLength` method return the `ValidatorFn` instead of `AsyncValidatorFn`.

```
getAsyncValidator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return this.service.pipe(
            map(options => {
                return Validators.minLength(options.minLength)
            ));
        }
}
```

Comment: …why…would you want to…?

Comment: I am using api to get validation options and I want to inject it into asnyc validator.
As you see here, I have the `minLength` from api.
And I don't want to rewirte the logic from sync validator.

Comment: Ah right, gotcha. This is probably not the right approach. The async validator runs every time the input changes while you really only need to get the config once. So you’re better of getting the config (somewhere) first and then setup your form..

Comment: good point, thank you